# Question about molecules and their movement

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics, disorder

This question might be nonsensical and, if it is, please leave a reply so I know and can remove it.

I'm currently learning about basic thermodynamics and was thinking, if there is some "average" or median movement pattern or velocity which a system of molecules reach after some time has gone.
Is there some "standard" of movement that any system follows given time or does it depend too much on the environment to answer?

I am asking this because the physics literature I'm reading just introduced the concept of disorder, and I wanted to know if that disorder is predictable or not.

Again sorry, if this is too vague or not really an answerable question. Just pm and I'll remove the post =)

Comment: You are talking about statistical distributions, like, e.g., Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution? (Just throwing in some keywords, to motivate your own exploration.)

Comment: Just searched for this and it kind of looks like what I was looking for, thanks! I'm admittedly not at the stage to understand this stuff yet but it was just really interesting to see. Are there more fields or topics which cover "predicting unordered systems"? Maybe it's just all one big topic and I don't know that

Comment: You will have to start distinguishing statistical physics, chaos theory and disordered systems - these are really different things... very different sometimes :)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I'm going to research on those keywords you just wrote and try to get a better grasp on each topic. Have a good day! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a gas, the molecules are bouncing around at random, off of each other and the walls of the container (unless “contained” by gravity). They quickly fill any available volume and come to an average kinetic energy which is proportional to the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently learning about basic thermodynamics and was thinking, if
> there is some "average" or median movement pattern or velocity which a
> system of molecules reach after some time has gone.

If you are talking about a gas, then if enough time has gone by without any energy transfer to or from the gas, then it will be in internal thermal equilibrium. At that point there will be a average value of the kinetic energy, and thus speed, of the gas molecules that is directly related to the temperature of a gas, particularly for an ideal gas.

But the speeds of individual gas molecules will statistically vary about the average and is given by the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, which you apparently have looked up.

Hope this helps.